# SAML implementation using OneLogin in ColdFusion throwing error

Tags: java, coldfusion, saml-2.0, onelogin, coldfusion-2018

As part of learning how to integrate OneLogin SSO in my ColdFusion app I pulled this git repo - 
**https://github.com/GiancarloGomez/ColdFusion-OneLogin** and set up locally. But, while sending the auth request to OneLogin we are getting an error message saying "***We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.***"

I could not find the root cause of this issue. Appreciate your timely help on this.

Configuration on OneLogin looks like below. Note that consumer URL I modified to http://127.0.0.1:8500/coldfusion-onelogin/consume.cfm instead of actual format mentioned (http://127.0.0.1:8500/coldfusion-onelogin/consume/) in the YouTube video provided in the readme file of this git repo. I had tried changing the consumer URL format as this http://127.0.0.1:8500/coldfusion-onelogin/consume/ but we are still getting the error message.

[image]

Access Tab in OneLogin looks like below,

[image]

Below is the code which sends auth request to OneLogin.

```
<cfscript>
  try{

    // used to encode string - chose to use Java version just in case CF did not encode correctly
    // encodeForURL appears to work but to keep the same as the samples from OneLogin I will use the Java reference
    urlEncoder = createObject("java","java.net.URLEncoder");

    // the appSettings object contain application specific settings used by the SAML library
    appSettings = createObject("java","com.onelogin.AppSettings");

    // set the URL of the consume file for this app. The SAML Response will be posted to this URL
    appSettings.setAssertionConsumerServiceUrl(request.company.getConsumeUrl());

    // set the issuer of the authentication request. This would usually be the URL of the issuing web application
    appSettings.setIssuer(request.company.getIssuerUrl());

    // the accSettings object contains settings specific to the users account.
    accSettings = createObject("java","com.onelogin.AccountSettings");

    // The URL at the Identity Provider where to the authentication request should be sent
    accSettings.setIdpSsoTargetUrl("https://app.onelogin.com/saml/signon/" & request.company.getIssuerID());

    // Generate an AuthRequest and send it to the identity provider
    authReq = createObject("java","com.onelogin.saml.AuthRequest").init(appSettings, accSettings);

    // now send to one login
    location ( accSettings.getIdp_sso_target_url() & "?SAMLRequest=" & authReq.getRidOfCRLF(urlEncoder.encode(authReq.getRequest(authReq.base64),"UTF-8")), false);
  }
catch(Any e){
    writeDump(e);
}
</cfscript>
```

Below is the format of auth request URL ,

https://app.onelogin.com/saml/signon/[issuerId]?SAMLRequest=[SamlRequest].

I am not providing the actual URL here since I am not sure whether someone can tamper it or not. But please do let us know if it is really required to solve this issue.

Below is the screenshot of the SAML Login Page , from here I am clicking on the button and send auth request to OneLogin.

[image]

Also, In the index.cfm , form action attribute is "/post/". Since it was throwing an error I had to replace it with "/coldfusion-onelogin/post.cfm". Here coldfusion-onelogin is a folder under wwwroot. Any settings in ColdFusion to be modified so that it will not throw any error if we keep the form action attribute as "/post/" ?.

Comment: Did this ever get solved? Were any of the answers suited to you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first logout from the OneLogin Admin Panel

https://app.onelogin.com/logout

To successfully test the demo app.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. The consumer URL validator is supposed to be a regex expression, and I'm not sure how it's going to handle a literal HTTP value (since it'll try to evaluate it as regex)

So try changing URL validator to be something dumb like `*.` (match everything)

That should hopefully clear the error until you can sort out what you want the validation to be in production.